# NodeJs Docker deployment on google cloud run

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy my NodeJs app on google cloud run over last two days. I use cloudbuild.ymal and all the building process and deployment process were all done without error. But I somehow can't open the app after deployment.

[image]
Before I was getting error comming from the errorHandler middleware but It was gone after I set NODE_ENV = production. I still get this error
[image]

The app is working fine without error on my local machine with Docker and MongoDB.
Here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'docker/compose:1.19.0'
  args: ['up', '-d']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:latest', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:$COMMIT_SHA', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:$BUILD_ID', '.']
  id: 'build-image-ecommerce'
  timeout: 500s
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:$COMMIT_SHA']
  id: 'push-image-to-container-registry'
  waitFor: ['build-image-ecommerce']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - 'run'
  - 'deploy'
  - 'ecommerce'
  - '--image'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:$COMMIT_SHA'
  - '--region'
  - 'us-east4'
  - '--platform'
  - 'managed'
  - '--allow-unauthenticated'
  waitFor: ['push-image-to-container-registry']
  id: 'deploy-to-cloud-run'
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:latest'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:$COMMIT_SHA'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ecommerce:$BUILD_ID'
```

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const colors = require('colors')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const authRoute = require('./Routes/authRoute')
const productRoute = require('./Routes/productRoute')
const orderRoute = require('./Routes/orderRoute')

const { errorHandler, notFound } = require('./Middlewares/errorMiddleware')


// DB Connection 
connectDB()

dotenv.config()

const app = express()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}
app.use(express.json())

//Routes
app.use('/api/users', authRoute)
app.use('/api/products', productRoute)
app.use('/api/orders', orderRoute)


// Error Middlewares
app.use(errorHandler)
app.use(notFound)


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 


app.listen(PORT, console.log(`App is running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`.blue.underline))
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml very simple setup

```
version: '3'
services:
  app: 
    container_name: ecommerceApi
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
    links: 
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment: 
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin 
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

Here is Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am using MongoDB as database, I do have another as well. How do I migrate some data to the db while working with Docker i.e run command like npm run data:import to import data in the db. I tried some ways but I didn't work for me. I could do it **docker exec -it  sh** and run the command but on production this process to be automated.

Please any help solving these issues, thanks in advance!!

Comment: There are many problems. 1) Cloud Run does not support Docker Compose. 2) The URL is using the route '/' but your app does not have that route so you will get 404. 3) Cloud Run does not support storage persistence. 4) If your app depends on Mongo, it will break in Cloud run as it is not deployed in your Dockerfile. 5) Read the Cloud Run documentation so that you understand which features are available and which are not.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much :) Which of the google options like App Engine, Cloud Run,  etc, can I deploy my app just for test. I just want to be familiar with GCP deployment.

Comment: I would start with Google Compute Engine. You can install Docker, Docker Compose, etc. Then learn about the various Google Cloud Features.

Comment: Cloud Run + MongoDB Atlas is the best/fully managed environment for your app. You can start for free with a small (and not so much secured) MongoDB instance on Atlas, and Cloud Run has a generous free tier.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks a lot. I came to see your response. I tried a second time to deploy using only dockerfile and mongo DB Atlas separately but I still got the same error. Not found

Comment: Can you add `/api/users` at the end of your url?

Comment: Oh my gosh it's working just fine.... I struggle a lot because of this. I forgot to add /api/users. Thank you so much again :))))